# Build ROS from source from scratch

Tags: ros, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all:

ros wiki has already shown one method for installing everything from source
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source#Installing_from_source

However, those special commands including

```
rosinstall_generator
wstool
rosdep
etc.
```

make the compilation even more obscure.
Users like me still prefer using traditional

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

to have everything built from scratch.

Should there be such a manual for ROS installation from source, instead of this wiki page
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source#Installing_from_source ????

Best Regards
Pei

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207169/build-ros-from-source-from-scratch.../) by [jiapei100](https://answers.ros.org/users/1310/jiapei100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-04-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-15**:
Please do **not** double post you questions: https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/81

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The workflow you describe is common for `autotools` and only applies to build and install a single package.

ROS packages are using CMake and the standard workflow for CMake packages is:

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

Actually with CMake you should always do an out-of-source build but that is another topics.

But the additional steps in the ROS-from-source instruction perform *additional* steps which are not covered by a per-package build.

`rosinstall_generator` creates a list of repositories which you need to clone based on a set of packages you want to build. The information where these repositories are and what dependencies they need is specific to ROS. I don't think that this functionality is cover by any other tool (except `apt-*`). Usually you would collect this information manually by reading instructions.

`wstool` then clones all repositories. Again this is not something you usually do when building a single package. And for multiple packages you would clone them one-by-one by hand.

`rosdep` then makes sure that you install all dependencies. Commonly you would read the install instructions and then manually install the deps e.g. using `apt-get install`.

The last step you did not mention `catkin_make_isolated` then determines the topological order of all your source packages which it does based on the package dependencies declared in their manifests. Then it invokes the stand `cmake / make / make install` steps for each package.

As you can see each step has a very good reason and for most of them nothing similar exists as a standard. Most of this automation is provided because ROS makes it easy for you to build hundreds of packages at once. You could still perform every task manually as you might be used to from other projects but it would take you hours to clone, install deps, build and install a bigger workspace like ROS desktop. These commands provide the automation to perform it in minutes (excluding the compilation time).

**Update:**

As every Linux distribution ROS has to choose a specific version of every package. For ROS Indigo that is Gazebo 2 - simply because nothing else was available when ROS Indigo was released almost a year ago.

`rosdep` makes the common task to install the default dependencies easy. Therefore it tries to pull in Gazebo 2. But it is perfectly valid for you to not use Gazebo 2 but Gazebo 5 instead. Most packages in ROS will compile fine against the newer version as well. Just use for similar question on this platform to find user doing exactly that.

The same for your embedded setup. You can install any Gazebo version from the source you want, e.g. build a custom version from source if you like. And then build the ROS packages on-top. If some packages don't work well with different versions of their dependencies (which is sometimes the case) the maintainers are usually happy to take contributions to make it more flexible.

All the scripts and packages you refer to are documentation in the ros wiki. The wiki pages also point to their repositories on GitHub where you will find all the source code. Since most of the tools are Python you could actually read all of the sources on your local machine already.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiapei100](https://answers.ros.org/users/1310/jiapei100/) on 2015-04-16**:
~/ros_catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gazebo2] Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package gazebo2 ERROR: the following rosdeps failed

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for your prompt but detailed reply. Still obscure anyway.

For instance,

`~/ros_catkin_ws$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gazebo2]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gazebo2
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y gazebo2] failed`

This clealy tells in order to install ROS, gazebo2 should be pre-installed. However, current Gazebo is of version 5.0 http://www.gazebosim.org/ . If there is such a flexibility for the users to pick up which version of a particular package he/she would like to install, that would be more user-friendly, right?

What's more, in my case, I'm installing ROS on an Embedded system. The default repository doesn't come with gazebo2. At least, there should be such a flexitility for us to  modify the rosdep scripts, instead of knowing nothing about what's going on.
Right?

Therefore, is there any chance for me to know the scripts

`rosinstall_generator
wstool
rosdep
catkin_make_isolated`

line by line??

Cheers
Pei

---

Originally posted by [jiapei100](https://answers.ros.org/users/1310/jiapei100/) with karma: 31 on 2015-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-16**:
Since this is not an "answer" please append additions like this to your original question.